# FFMPEG version updating issue

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg library in one of my android project. I am using this library.

https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

But it is using very old ffmpeg version. So I want to update ffmpeg version. I have used this library to compile ffmpeg version 3.3.3

https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android

now if i am running this command in terminal ffmpeg -version. I am getting the correct output as
ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers

Now i want to update ffmpeg version in 
https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java
this library so i changed assets file to my compile ffmpeg file. But if i run the app and check version i am getting this output 
ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developersbuilt with gcc 4.9.x

I dont know why ffmpeg version is not changing. I have run command ndk-build as well after entering in jni folder but still ffmpeg version is not changing.
Please suggest me any solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: have you any solution for this?